# how to store tableview cell checkmark state in popover?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, nsuserdefaults

I am having few buttons in initial view controller. A popover with an expandable tableview will appear on click of any button. I am using single popover for all the buttons with different data to be shown on tableview. The selected items in the popover when I am clicking on the first button is being removed when I am clicking on the other buttons so as to all. The selected items is gonna saved into an array based on indexpath.row. An exception error is coming while I am trying to remove the selected items from the same array based on same indexpath.row.

How can i store the checkmark on each cell selection for all popover ?

Here is a piece of my code

```
func expandableTableView(_ expandableTableView: LUExpandableTableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let selectedService = arrData[indexPath.section].Children?[indexPath.row].EnglishName ?? ""
    let inPrice = arrData[indexPath.section].Children?[indexPath.row].InPrice ?? 0
    print("service and price : \(selectedService) \(inPrice)")
    let selectedItem = (" \(selectedService) \(inPrice)")
    let cell: UITableViewCell? = expandableTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    if cell?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
    {
        cell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
        selectionArr.append(selectedItem)
        inPriceCount =  inPrice
    }
    else
    {
        cell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
            selectionArr.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            inPriceCount =  -inPrice
    }
    self.delegate?.messageData(data: selectionArr as AnyObject)
    self.delegate?.inPrice(data: inPriceCount as AnyObject)
    let rowToSelect = [expandableTableView .indexPathForSelectedRow]
    print(rowToSelect)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not remove any thing from array. Just add a key on every index

```
dict["ischeckMarked"]=false
```

When you change tap on checkmark change it true

```
dict["ischeckMarked"]=true
```

If already checked and now you want to unmark change it to false

```
dict["ischeckMarked"]=false
```

Hope this will help you out.